# Link has a reference in the workbook that may not exist—link not working after it formerly did

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to troubleshoot what can be wrong with hyperlinks in my excel document. It formerly worked but recently stopped. I'm unsure why. The document is hosted on sharepoint, so the link has only ever worked in a browser, but that isn't even working anymore.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Formula:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDEX('Launch Playbook Detail'!$B$14:$B$360,SMALL(IF(($F$4='Launch Playbook Detail'!$A$14:$A$360),ROW('Launch Playbook Detail'!$A$14:$A$360)-MIN(ROW('Launch Playbook Detail'!$B$14:$B$360))+1,373-11+1),ROWS($G$1:G1)))),IFERROR(INDEX('Launch Playbook Detail'!$B$14:$B$360,SMALL(IF(($F$4='Launch Playbook Detail'!$A$14:$A$360),ROW('Launch Playbook Detail'!$A$14:$A$360)-MIN(ROW('Launch Playbook Detail'!$B$14:$B$360))+1,""),ROWS($G$1:G1))),"")),"")
```

I'm using Excel 2016. Here is where the link is and the error being showed.

[image]

Then the sheet it is going to:
[image]

Comment: hmmm, sharepoint. Did you by chance do some kind of synchronization with one drive? I did that once and it messed up links to other workbook. But if all of your links are internal to the file, then maybe not.

Comment: @gns100 I do have onedrive on, but the file is held in a Teams location. The link isn't working for me and everyone else. How did you fix your links?

Comment: I deleted the sync. So if you open one drive and can see the sharepoint library there then you are synced. I deleted this one drive folder NOT the actual sharepoint library. Since the link is not working for everyone, I don't think this is the issue, but just wanted to share.